# What are the properties of the solution of a nonlinear programming with linear objective function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In a constrained nonlinear programming with a linear objective function, are there any results/properties of the solution?

The constraints are nonlinear nonconvex.

Answer (score 1):

Any optimization problem whatsoever can be expressed as a constrained nonlinear programming problem with a linear objective function, because the problem
\begin{align}
\operatorname{minimize} & \quad f(x) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x \in S
\end{align}
(with optimization variable $x$)
is equivalent to the problem
\begin{align}
\operatorname{minimize} & \quad t \\
\text{subject to} & \quad t \geq f(x) \\
&\quad x \in S
\end{align}
(with optimization variables $x$ and $t$).

So no, there is not much that you can say about the solution to such a general problem.